# Test whether the following sets are connected or not.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

> Which of the following sets are connected ?
>
> (A) $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:x,y\in \Bbb Q\}\subset \Bbb R^2$.
>
> (B) $\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2:\text{ at least one of } x,y \text{ is rational }\}\subset \Bbb R^2$.
>
> (C) $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:\text{ either } x,y\in \mathbb Q \text{ or } x,y\in \mathbb R\setminus \Bbb Q\}\subset \Bbb R^2$.

**My Thought :**

(C) The given set $$\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:\text{ either } x,y\in \mathbb Q \text{ or } x,y\in \mathbb R\setminus \Bbb Q\}$$

$$=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:y=mx\text{ where, } m\in \mathbb Q\}$$

Clearly the set is path connected, as there is always a path between any two points through origin. So, it is connected.

But, I could not conclude about (A) & (B).

Please help...

Comment: @JessePFrancis, the instance you mentioned is (B).

Comment: What I was trying to say is, in C, there are no points with x rational, y irrational (or other way around) which is there in $\mathbb R^2$, hence set in C cannot be $\mathbb R^2$

Comment: @  Nameless ): $(\sqrt 2,1)\in \mathbb R^2$ but not in $C$

Comment: I think (A) is not connected because $(-\infty,\pi) \times (-\infty, \infty) \cup (\pi,\infty) \times (-\infty, \infty)$ covers $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another proof for the connectedness of $C$:

First, we consider the subset $S \subset C$ which consists of rational translates of the lines $\{(x, -x) \mid x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ and $\{(x, x) \mid x \in \mathbb{R}\}$. These are all contained in $C$, and moreover form a dense subset of $C$ which is path-connected, and hence connected.

All we now need is the following lemma, which I will leave as an easy exercise.

**Lemma**: If $S \subset C$ is connected and dense, then $C$ is connected.

Comment: Very nice..!!! As $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:y=mx\text{ where, } m\in \mathbb Q\}$ is connected and dense subset of $C$ so $C$ is connected

Comment: Ah, yes; that makes this argument even nicer.

Answer (score 4):

The set $A$ is not connected, because its projection into $\mathbb R$ is $\mathbb Q$, which is not connected.

The set $B$ is connected. Indeed, $B$ contains the vertical lines $x=a\in\mathbb Q$ and the horizontal ones $y=b\in\mathbb Q$. Clearly we can move from any point with one coordinate rational to $(0,0)$ using these lines. Hence $B$ is path-connected.

Finally, the set $C=\mathbb Q^2\cup (\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q)^2$ is connected, but the argument requires some care, because a point $(\alpha,\beta)$ with irrational coordinates may have *irrational* slope $\beta/\alpha$.

One part of the idea works, anyway: for $p=(a,b)\in\mathbb Q^2$ the line $L$ through the origin $O=(0,0)$ and $p$ lies inside $C$, because the slope is *rational*. Thus the segment $[O,p]$ is contained in $C$. With this we check connectedness of $C$ directly from the definition.

Suppose $C$ is the union of two disjoint subsets $U,V\subset C$, both open in $C$; say $(0,0)\in U$. Since every segment $[O,p]$ is connected, we deduce $[O,p]\subset U$ for every $p\in\mathbb Q^2$. In particular $\mathbb Q^2\subset U$. Now, $\mathbb Q^2$ is dense in $C$ (it is in $\mathbb R^2$), and consequently $U$ is 
also dense in $C$. But $U$ is closed in $C$, since its complement $V=C\setminus U$ is open, and we conclude $U=X$. We are done.

Comment: From your answer it is clear to me that $A$ is disconnected..I already proved that $C$ is connected..But in your answer $B$ is NOT clear to me..Here , $B=(\Bbb Q\times \Bbb R)\cup (\Bbb R\times \Bbb Q)\cup (\Bbb Q\times \Bbb Q)$. How it is complement of $\Bbb Q\times \Bbb Q$ ?

Comment: What I say is that your proof that $C$ is connected seems incomplete, because $(\alpha,\beta)$ both irrational with irrational quotient do not fit your description $y=mx$, $m\in\mathbb Q$. Concerning $B$, you're right, I was doing the set "at least one component is irrational". I'm editing the post.

Comment: Well..now _B_ is very clear....But I still don't understand about $C$..What do you mean by irrational quotient...

Comment: For instance $(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ is in the set, but not in any line $y=mx$, because $m$ should be $\sqrt{3/2}\notin\mathbb Q$. Hence the set $C$ contains but is not equal to $\{y=mx, m\in\mathbb Q\}$.